# Starting Rails Instance Server from an absolute path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I'm trying to create a autostart script to start a Rails Instance Server when my SUSE Linux Server is restarting.

I've created a shell script in /etc/init.d/rails_s_appname with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/appname/public_html/rails s -p 3333 -d
```

I gave the script 755 permissions and started it.

The result is the following:

```
/etc/init.d/rails_s_appname 
/etc/init.d/rails_s_appname: line 2: /home/appname/public_html/rails: No such file or directory
```

Any one has an idea how to start a Rails Instance Server from an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better do not use the rails script to launch your app like that.

Try Thin or unicorn. Both have the cwd configuration to say where is you APP_HOME

But if you really want do that. Use the script/rails commandline inside your APP_HOME to do what you want

```
/home/appname/script/rails s -p 3333 -d
```

Comment: Normally I use Passenger to run my apps, but I needed a temporary solution on this server. So thanks for your quick response =).